# Replace certain field from file with user input for each row and save in same file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Im typing to write a script which can read **file_name**, **delimiter** and **field_number**. After that for each row take an input, replace the field (specified by **field_number**) and output to same file.

For example if the input is as follows:

```
Ritesh;M;1992
Shakya;F;1993
```

For the command

```
bash_script.sh test.csv ";" 3
```

Iterating through each row if I input **1994** for first and 1995 for second. I want the output to be the as follows caved in the same file.

```
Ritesh;M;1994
Shakya;F;1995
```

So far i managed to get upto this point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Following is the input needed:";
echo "\$1: FILE_NAME";
echo "\$2: DELIMITER";
echo "\$3: FIELD IN NUMERIC VALUE";

gawk -i inplace -F "$2" '{...}' $1;
```

Also my version of `gawk` doesn't support -i.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "input from reader"? How will the script be run? How will you be giving the replacement patterns? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: AFAIK, GU `awk` doesn't support in-place editing of files, nor does any other version of `awk`.  `-i` tells GNU `awk` to include a file (or as `man awk` says, `Load an awk source library`).  It doesn't matter - every tool that does support in-place editing (like `perl` or `sed`), just does it via writing to a tmp file and mv-ing it into place afterwards or some similar method anyway.  you can do the same.

Comment: @cas recent versions of GNU `awk` (and maybe others) can take `-i inplace` which makes them act like `sed -i`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace

Comment: ok, that must be **very** recent because it's not in debian sid yet - I have gawk 1:4.1.3+dfsg-0.1 installed and there's no mention of `-i inplace` in the man page.  Hmmmm....unless `inplace` is an awk library, loaded by `-i`.......oh, it is.  `/usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`.  neat.  it's mentioned in the info docs, but not in the man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from @ClaudioM I found the answer I was looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "${3}" ];then
        echo "Usage: <filename> <delimiter> <field_no>"
else
        FILENAME=$1
        DELIMITER=$2
        FIELD_NO=$3
        TEMP_FILE=/tmp/tempFile
        if [ -f $TEMP_FILE ]; then
            rm $TEMP_FILE
        fi
        OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'
        for line in $(cat $FILENAME)
        do
                echo $line
                oldValue=`echo $line|cut -d$DELIMITER -f$FIELD_NO`
                echo "Enter the value to replace [$oldValue]"
                read newValue
                echo $line | awk -F "$DELIMITER" '{$'$FIELD_NO'="'$newValue'"}{print}' OFS=$DELIMITER >> $TEMP_FILE;IFS=$OLDIFS
        done
fi
mv $TEMP_FILE $FILENAME
```